# Opening a chrome tab and get control on it from a Java app

Tags: java, bash, chromium

I'm building an application to edit some html/css directly from a server. It works fine but I want to open chromium or firefox on the edited page to render the result.
I can open a new tab with the CLI with:

```
chromium-browser http://www.google.com
```

But if I re-call this command it opens a new tab.

How can I get control on the tab to close it and re-open a new tab ?
Or can I replace the url of the tab directly from de CLI ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you display the `HTML` in `Java` through `JEditorPane`

Comment: Because I think the render is better in a real browser. It can support latest HTML5 components and flash.

Comment: Then try a java parser like http://jsoup.org/. It parses HTML5

Comment: It's a parser but it doesn't render the page...

Comment: You can try to display the parsed data

Comment: Try http://www.asual.com/summer